# Convert Integer[] to Long[] in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for the most efficient and hopefully without loops method to convert an array of integers to an array of longs.

I was hoping to do something like this

```
Arrays.asList(ids).toArray(new Long(ids.length));
```

but it won't work.

Comment: There is no way to do this magically without a loop - and even if you don't write the loop yourself, some library function that you'd call would contain a loop.

Comment: I understand that it would, as long as it efficient and makes my code more clean and hide those routines

Comment: @antohoho Then write the loop yourself, put it in a utility method and call that method. AFAIK there's no helper function in the JDK that does that.

Comment: Its one loop method. I would just write the method and call it done.

Comment: Do you actually need the conversion? Both extend Number, providing longValue...

Answer (score 3):

This looks pretty clean to me.

```
Stream.of(ids).map(Long::valueOf).toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Comment: it's for sure looks very cool, however I do not have Java 8, looking for solution for Java 7

Comment: @antohoho Java 8 is not something new (it was released over one year ago), so could you explain why you are looking for code for earlier versions? Are you not able to update your JMV or is it maybe for Android?

Comment: I am working on a project that few years old, so did not have chance to update environment

Comment: Old projects should be able to work on new version of Java (because of backward compatibility). I assume you are in situation where "if something works fine, don't you dare to play around with it". In that case you have no luck because there is no method in standard version of Java which would make `Integer[] -> Long[]` transition easier, so you will need to use standard loops (you can wrap your code inside some utility method if you are going to use it often).

Comment: pretty much what happening. Will just write a loop, but for now at least I am sure there is no standard method. I love Java 8 solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just write it your self. Its really not so bad.

```
public static Long[] toLongArray(Integer[] ints) {
    Long[] result = new Long[ints.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Long.valueOf(ints[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```